# Apache Thrift over the Internet

Tags: c++, thrift

I am interested in using `Apache Thrift` to implement a communication protocol between a client and a c++ device. As I ran through the Documentation i noticed that this is easily possible usind `Thrift` in a local network. 
My question is, is it also possible to use `Thrift` to control my devices from outside the local network, i.e. from the internet? How would this work?

regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using socket or HTTP Transport, you're on the right way. Technically, for a typical client/server scenario, there is no difference between internal and external network. Only for bidi-communication scenarios the presence of firewalls may make things a little more complicated.

Comment: Can you give some resources which explains how to use Thrift over Http?

Comment: Same as with other transports. If you already have a socket Transport, replace it by THttpTransport. The THttpClient/THttpServer classes could be also worth a look.